# Deactivate a script from an echo statement within a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wanting to remove a script from a Woocommerce checkout page if conditions are met.

The script is injected from a plugin. The plugin authors have chosen to add this as an echo statement:

```
private function includeJavascript() {
          $trackjsUrl = str_replace('server.php', 'trackjs.php', $this->session->getUrl());
          echo '<script id="pap_x2s6df8d" src="'.$trackjsUrl.'" type="text/javascript"></script>';
      }
```

Because the script (#pap_x2s6df8d) has been added within an Echo statement, the usual functions to remove it do not work (e.g. **wp_deregister_script**)

I want to avoid editing the plugin. Is there another way around this?

This is how I would approach it if the script was enqued per Wordpress best practice:

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE['cookieexists']  ) ) {
  echo " // Cookie was found";
  echo " // deactive script";
  wp_deregister_script('pap_x2s6df8d'); 
  wp_dequeue_script( 'pap_x2s6df8d');
}
```

Unfortunately, the above fails as the scripts aren't registered / enqued.

Are there any alternatives I can try for this situation?

Comment: Apparently, there is no hook be used when the author didn't put it in. You could drop the issue in the plugin support or request the PR if available. instead of PHP solution, you could add the code to modify the type of script like `<script type='text/gzip'>` that the script would be disabled before the script execute.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this, is using your `.htaccess` file and redirect `trackjs.php` to another place where you just return nothing.

Say, the script you want to execute conditionally is this one: `http://localhost/wordpress/trackjs.php`. In `.htaccess` write something in the line of this before the Wordpress stuff:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^trackjs.php$ /wp-content/themes/my-theme/custom-theme-file.php [L]
```

(The actual implementation depends on your use case. You can try different rules [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).)
The `custom-theme-file.php` outputs an empty string:

```
<?php echo ''; wp_die(); ?>
```

Now the conditional part: In case you want this done in javascript, you could add the script again, but now append a query string to the url. In your `custom-theme-file.php` you can then read the query string parameter using `$_GET` and output the content of the original plugin file.

Does that make sense?